# "X" does not exist in this context

Tags: c#, xna

I don't understand the logic behind this error in the second section.

*The name 'newMove' does not exist in the current context.*

Isn't it define just above in the first section?

```
            //First section
            if (base.IsPlayer1 == true)
            {
                Move newMove = moveList.Detect();
            }
            else if (base.IsPlayer1 == false)
            {
                MoveKeyboard newMove = moveListKeyboard.DetectMove();
            }

            //Second section
            if (newMove != null)
            {
                 PlayMove();
            }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're seeing is a scope problem.  `newMove` is defined within the `if` or `else if` statement and is only accessible within whichever block created the variable.

You *could* define it above, but it looks like you have two different `Types` (`Move` and `MoveKeyboard`).  If you can consolidate those to the same type you could have a single definition above the first `if` statement.

Comment: This is the main problem. I can't manage consolidate them in the same type. But if this is the only solution, i'll keep on trying.

Comment: What's the difference between the two?  You may be able to use inheritance where each one has the same basic base class.  Barring that, you'll need to define two separate variables and test each of them in your second section.

Comment: @Pilispring I'm not necessarily recommending it, but you could make `newMove` `dyanmic`.

Comment: I'll try to increase my skills by consolidating the two classes. Thanks.

Comment: @Pilispring you could do that, but you can also set it to an object, and then cast it(using `typeof`, like this: `Move currentMove = (Move)newMove`)

Comment: I tried your way but I can't make it work somehow. They say that this solution would create conflict between the two scopes. They didn't want my "Move currentMove = (Move)newMove)" to overwrite the typeof definition

Answer (score 2):

Yes, its defined, but only for its *scope*. Since the second block is outside of that *scope*, you can't use it.

Scope is defined by curly braces (`{}`) and a section of code can access any variable within its scope, and *every scope it is inside of*.

```
       //Function scope
       //First section
        if (base.IsPlayer1 == true)
        {
            //If block scope
            Move newMove = moveList.Detect();
        }
        else if (base.IsPlayer1 == false)
        {
            // else if block scope
            MoveKeyboard newMove = moveListKeyboard.DetectMove();
        }

        //Function scope again, newMove is not available.
        //Second section
        if (newMove != null)
        {
             PlayMove();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Scoping.  In C# variables are only valid within the scope they are defined.  Braces, `{ }` denote a scope block.

If you move the definition of `newMove` to before your if statement, it'll work.

Also, since you are defining `newMove` in two different scopes, with two different types, you'll have to change something.

Answer (score 1):

all what you should do is to move the declration of `newmove` to outside the if else statement like this :

```
object newmove;
if (base.IsPlayer1 == true)
{
   newMove = moveList.Detect();
}
else
{
   newMove = moveListKeyboard.DetectMove();
}

//Second section
if (newMove != null)
{
   PlayMove();
}
```